# How to search messages by a hashtag (like #something) using the telethon libray?

Tags: telethon

Just searching messages using get_messages() does not work:

```
 client.get_messages(enity, search="#myhashtag")
```

Doesn't work. i.e. does not find messages like "A message with #myhashtag". How to search for messages by a hashtag ?

Comment: This was not a hash-tag related problem. See https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1602